# How to set the icon that is used to represent my app for Semantic Zoom on the Start Screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, .net-4.5, winrt-xaml

Where to configure icon for any application when metro desktop is in Semantic Zoom as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the "Small Logo" for your project, which is a 30x30 pixel image.

In Visual Studio, open up the Package.appxmanifest and it's the third option in the Tile section which you need to set.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in manifest file there is a property background under Tile sub heading its by default set as Grey hence we see grey border when start screen is in semantic view zoomed in. Just change the color according to the app icon